# Problem with implementation of the hierarchical state machine in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, state-machine

I have been attempting to implement a hierarchical state machine in C++. I have chosen the approach based on the State design pattern and the Composite design pattern. According to the Composite design pattern I have defined a common abstract base class for the atomic states (simple states) and the composite states (states consisting of state machines)

State.h

```
class State {
public:
    virtual void notifyCatenaryModeRequested(bool state) = 0;
    virtual void notifyBatteryModeRequested(bool state) = 0;
    virtual void notifyMainContactorsCloseRequested(bool state) = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
};
```

StateAtomic.h

```
#include "State.h"
#include "StateComposite.h"

class StateAtomic : public State {
public:
    StateAtomic(StateComposite* parent) : parent(parent) {}
    void notifyCatenaryModeRequested(bool state) {cat_mode_requested = state;}
    void notifyBatteryModeRequested(bool state) {bat_mode_requested = state;}
    void notifyMainContactorsCloseRequested(bool state) {main_contactors_close_requested = state;}
    virtual void update() = 0;

protected:
    StateComposite *parent;
    bool cat_mode_requested;
    bool bat_mode_requested;
    bool main_contactors_close_requested;
};
```

StateComposite.h

```
#include "State.h"

class StateComposite : public State {
public:
    StateComposite(StateComposite* parent) : parent(parent) {}
    void notifyCatenaryModeRequested(bool state) {active->notifyCatenaryModeRequested(state);}
    void notifyBatteryModeRequested(bool state) {active->notifyBatteryModeRequested(state);}
    void notifyMainContactorsCloseRequested(bool state) {main_contactors_close_requested = state;}
    void update() {active->update();}
    void switchState(State * new_state) {active = new_state;}
    
protected:
    StateComposite* parent;
    State* active;
};
```

According to the State design pattern, I have defined a class for the individual states of the state machine

Ready.h

```
#include "StateAtomic.h"

class StateMachine;

class Ready : public StateAtomic {
    public:
        Ready(StateMachine *parent) : StateAtomic(parent) {}
        void update() {
            std::cout << "Ready" << std::endl;
            if (cat_mode_requested && main_contactors_close_requested) {
                parent->switchState(& static_cast<StateMachine*>(parent)->cat);
                std::cout << "Switch to cat." << std::endl;
            } else if (bat_mode_requested && main_contactors_close_requested) {
                parent->switchState(& static_cast<StateMachine*>(parent)->bat);
                std::cout << "Switch to bat." << std::endl;
            }
    }
};
```

Cat.h

```
#include "StateComposite.h"
#include "CatPrecharge.h"
#include <iostream>

class StateMachine;

class Cat : public StateComposite {
public:

    Cat(StateMachine *parent) : StateComposite(parent) {}
    void update() {std::cout << "Cat" << std::endl;}
    
};
```

Then I have defined the top-level state machine

```
#include "StateComposite.h"
#include "StateAtomic.h"
#include "Ready.h"
#include "Cat.h"
#include <iostream>

class StateMachine : public StateComposite {
public:

    StateMachine() : StateComposite(nullptr), ready(this), cat(this) {
        active = &ready;
    }
    void update() {active->update();}

private:

    Ready ready;
    Cat cat;

    friend class Ready;
    friend class Cat;
};
```

And a very simple application

main.cpp

```
#include "StateMachine.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct command {
    bool cat_mode_requested;
    bool bat_mode_requested;
    bool main_contactors_close_requested;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    StateMachine state_machine;
    command active_command;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        std::cout << "Cat mode requested?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> active_command.cat_mode_requested;
        std::cout << "Bat mode requested?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> active_command.bat_mode_requested;
        std::cout << "Main contactors close requested?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> active_command.main_contactors_close_requested;

        state_machine.notifyCatenaryModeRequested(active_command.cat_mode_requested);
        state_machine.notifyBatteryModeRequested(active_command.bat_mode_requested);
        state_machine.notifyMainContactorsCloseRequested(active_command.main_contactors_close_requested);
        state_machine.update();
    }
}
```

I have found that the following steps result in program crash:

1. Invoking the `state_machine.update()`
2. Invoking `parent->switchState(& static_cast<StateMachine*>(parent)->cat)` inside the `Ready::update()`
3. Invoking the `state_machine.update()`

The problem is obviously in this statement: `parent->switchState(& static_cast<StateMachine*>(parent)->cat)` called from the `Ready::update()`.

Unfortunately, I don't understand why. Can anybody help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Content of the inherited sub-object `StateComposite` inside the `StateMachine` object:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, all this inheritance, that's required by strict compliance with Buzzword Bingo, makes it rather difficult to visually follow all that logic, and this is too long for a [mre], so the only question that can be asked here: what did your debugger show you, as the reason for the crash?

Comment: The problem is that the pointer `StateMachine::active` contains 0 after the  `parent->switchState(& static_cast<StateMachine*>(parent)->cat)` call.

Comment: Well, your debugger should be able to tell you the reason for that. Most debuggers have a facility for setting a watch that triggers a breakpoint any time a particular variable changes.

Comment: I have been using the GDB debugger under the NetBeans IDE v8.2. It seems to me that this debugger doesn't have this feature. During the stepping through the code I have noticed a strange content inside the StateComposite inherited sub-object inside the StateMachine object (please see the edit in my post). Please can you tell me whethe you have any explanation for that?

Comment: Of course it does. I use it every day. The w)atch command.

Comment: Thank you. I have just added the `StateMachine::active` into the watch. What I have found is that it really changes its value to 0x0 but it seems to me that it happens after calling the `active->notifyCatenaryModeRequested(state);` inside the `StateComposite::notifyCatenaryModeRequested(bool state)`

Comment: Sounds great, looks like you found the problem.

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't understand why that happens.

Comment: You'll just have to try figure it out. As I gently mentioned at the beginning: over-reliance on Buzzword Bingo by attempting to implement every so-called "design pattern" under the sun often results in over-engineered, overly-complex code that's impossible to follow and understand, based on reading it. The only way to understand it is to debug it. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow is not a debugging site, we don't debug code for others.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think you are not helpful. Following a suggested design is not buzzword bingo. The example is also very well constructed and not too large for understanding it.

Comment: What is Cat? Another state?

Comment: Yes, it is a "composite" state.

Comment: I tried to build the example and it doesn't work. Why don't you update/prune it so that one can build it?

Comment: That is exactly the reason why a [mcve] is required, it's supposed to weed out this kind of problem which just needs a bit of care, patience and discipline.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I am sorry. I have done a couple of typos and I have forgotten to append also the `Cat` class definition. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the program crashes is that the `active` member inside the `Cat`  composite state hasn't been initialized.

Comment: My gut feeling is that `StateComposite` already should initialize `active`. Ideally that state would already be passed via the constructor so that it's impossible not to initialize it. Additionally it looks as if `StateComposite` should be an abstract base class (considering that probably only derived concrete classes will ever be instantiated). One option is to make the constructor (which would require a `State *` argument for `active`) protected. (ctd.)#

Comment: (... ctd.)  The `Cat` and `Bat` constructors would then call the `StateComposite` base class constructor with that argument instead of "manually" assigning the base class member in the `Cat` constructor body which looks fishy.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative method for this that I used for interrupt handlers in device drivers. Using logically stacked pointers to end action functions for what to do at the end of each interrupt. One advantage of this is if an additional step needs to be added at some level, it just uses another function for that step at that level. I recall a driver that had over 200 cases in a switch case statement to handle this, which was simplified by switching to 3 logical levels of end action handlers.

```
typedef void (*PTRFUN)()                // pointer to function

void fun_driver()
{
    PTRFUN pflvl0 = fun_lvl00;          // what to do at next level 0
    PTRFUN pllvl1 = fun_lvl10;          // what to do at next level 1
    // ...                              // start some operation
    return;
}

void fun_int()                          // interrupt function
{
    // ...
    pflvl1();                           // call lvl1 handler
    return;
}

void fun_lvl10()
{
    pflvl1 = fun_lvl11;                 // next interrupt goes to lvl11
    // ...
    return;
}

void fun_lvl11()
{
    pflvl1 = fun_lvl10;                 // reset back to lvl10
    pflvl0();                           // call higher level
    return;
}

void fun_lvl00()
{
    // ...                              // set a completion status
    // ...                              // so OS handles end of operation action
    return;
}
```